# Loop Through Object and get output into HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having some trouble understanding what bit of Javascript to use to loop through the below object to then output into HTML. The aim is to output the values from the object on to the page something like the HTML Output.

```
{
   "lineItems":{
      "physicalItems":[
         {
            "id":70,
            "productId":362,
            "name":"Sample Product 1 ",
            "sku":"290909",
            "quantity":1,
            "isTaxable":true,
            "discounts":[

            ],
            "discountAmount":0,
            "listPrice":130,
            "salePrice":130,
            "extendedListPrice":130,
            "extendedSalePrice":130,
            "extendedComparisonPrice":130,
            "categories":[

            ],
            "type":"physical",
            "variantId":593
         },
         {
            "id":69,
            "productId":383,
            "name":"Sample Product",
            "sku":"280910",
            "quantity":1,
            "isTaxable":true,
            "discounts":[

            ],
            "discountAmount":0,
            "listPrice":350,
            "salePrice":350,
            "extendedListPrice":350,
            "extendedSalePrice":350,
            "extendedComparisonPrice":350,
            "categories":[

            ],
            "type":"physical",
            "variantId":685
         }
      ],
      "digitalItems":[

      ],
      "giftCertificates":[

      ]
   }
}
```

HTML Output Required

```
PhysicalItems 1 - Sample Product 1
SalePrice 1 - 130
PhysicalItems 2 - Sample Product
SalePrice 2 - 350
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript to loop through obj['lineItems']['physicalItems']

Comment: Thanks for the response @Kudlas

Answer (score 1):

Your cleanest options would be to use a templating framework like mustache.js or handlebarsjs.

However, with ES6 JavaScript you can do something like this:

```
const lineItems = require("./lineItems.json");

/**
* @param {string} type
*/
const createMarkupFor = type => {

const markup = `
   <ul>
       ${lineItems[type].map((lineItem, index) => (`
            <li>
                PhysicalItems ${index + 1} - Sample Product ${lineItem.name}
             </li>
             <li>
                SalesPrice ${index + 1} - ${lineItem.salePrice}
             </li>
        `))}
    </ul>`
    
    document.body.innerHTML = markup;
};

createMarkupFor("physicalItems");
```